# env command with functions defined in bashrc

Tags: rhel, environment-variables, bash-functions

I have a function in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
foo () { echo $FOO }
```

Now, this works:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ setenv FOO "yes"
$ foo
yes
```

But this doesn't:

```
$ env FOO="no" foo
foo: no such file or directory
```

---

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: presumably there's a semicolon after `echo $FOO`?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your use of `setenv`; that's a (t)csh-ism; what shell(s) are you working with here?

Answer (score 2):

So, you have this:

```
$ foo() { echo "$FOO"; }
$ FOO=bar foo
bar
```

So:

```
$ env FOO=bar foo
env: foo: No such file or directory
```

Where is `env` looking for the command? `info man` declares:

> The first operand that does not contain the character '=' specifies
>   the program to invoke; it is searched for according to the 'PATH'
>   environment variable.

Hmm. Well, `foo` is a bash function, so what if we invoke bash

```
$ env FOO=bar bash -c foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

Oh, wait, you defined the function in your ~/.bashrc, and if we look at [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the bash manual, we see that the shell sources your .bashrc for *interactive* shells:

```
$ env FOO=bar bash -ic foo
bar
```

There we go.

Comment: or possibly `env BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bashrc" FOO=bar bash -c foo`

Comment: yes, very nice.